# Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8443]]

Tags: linux, ssl, tomcat, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to enable SSL on Tomcat (running custom domain on Ubunbu instance on Google Compute Engine).

I created Let's Encrypt certificate, it created 4 files under `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com`:

```
cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
```

Then:

```
cd /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com

openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out pkcs.p12 -name tomcat

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass mypassword -destkeypass mypassword -destkeystore
KeyStore.jks -srckeystore pkcs.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass mypassword -alias
tomcat

sudo cp KeyStore.jks /opt/tomcat/conf/.keystore
```

Enable connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
    URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/conf/.keystore" keystorePass="mypassword" keyAlias="tomcat"
/>
```

I get the error:

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8443]]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I check the keystore with

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /opt/tomcat/conf/.keystore
```

it lists the certificate (I presume correctly).

I have port 8443 allowed (but I also get the same error for 443). If I comment out this connector I'm able to connect to mydomain over http just fine.

What am I missing in this process? I've read many posts on this topic but I can't seem to figure out what else is required. Everything seems to be working correctly except the connector.

Comment: Could anyone help out with this? Seems like a very common scenario - Ubuntu, Tomcat, Java app, letsencrypt, trying to enable SSL